# Makefile expanding variables

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like to perform expansion on a variable that might contain references to other variables.  I'll illustrate with an example:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
X = foo bar baz $(foreach x, a b c, $$(value $(x))) qux
$(info $(X))
```

If you run this makefile, it prints:

```
foo bar baz $(value a) $(value b) $(value c) qux
```

I'd like to know how to expand it so that I get:

```
foo bar baz 1 2 3 qux
```

I can do the following:

```
$(eval X = $(X))
```

To get close to what I want, however this requires me to reassign the variable again.  Also, I'm `eval`ing whatever was in the whole variable which may not be what I want.  I'd like to be able to do something like `$(expand X)` and have the resulting text.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you wanted and provide a minimal working example. It's very unclear from you post here and comment under the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```
X = $(foreach x, a b c, $($(x)))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite make my example right, I end up with a variable containing something like "foo bar baz $(somevar) $(some-other-var)".

I'd like to expand $(somevar) and $(some-other-var).

I am/was aware of how to indirectly expand a variable reference when that is all a variable contains.

Comment: @BitShifter: I've given this a lot of thought, and I just can't see how to do it. My best guess is to use SECONDEXPANSION (which my version of gmake doesn't have) and take `$(X)` as the prerequisite of a dummy rule. If that doesn't work there may still exist some horrible hack that will do it, but I have no idea what it might be.